# Why value of member variable is changing?

Tags: c++, linked-list, pointer-to-member

Here is a linked list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Arrival
{
    string arrAddress;
    double distance;
    string roadCategory;
    struct Arrival* next;
};


class ArrivalList
{
    private:
        struct Arrival* head;

    public:

        bool addArrival(string oneAddress, double distance, string roadCategory);


};


bool ArrivalList::addArrival(string oneAddress, double distance, string roadCategory)
{
    Arrival* temp;
    Arrival* current=new Arrival();
    current=head;
    temp=new Arrival();
    temp->arrAddress=oneAddress;
    temp->distance=distance;
    temp->roadCategory=roadCategory;
    int f=0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(current==NULL)
        {
            temp->next=NULL;
            head=temp;
            f=1;
            break;

        }
        else if(oneAddress>=current->arrAddress && oneAddress<current->next->arrAddress)
        {
            temp->next=current->next;
            current->next=temp;
            f=1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            current=current->next;
        }
    }
    cout<<head->arrAddress;
   if(f)
   {
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
}


int main()
{
    ArrivalList li;
    li.addArrival("jjjjj",0.8999,"I");
    li.addArrival("aaaaa",0.888,"k");


}
```

I want the value of head persist within the multiple call to the function addArrival.But it is changing.I want to to start the loop from 'current' value which should be the value of head after the first call but it is changing and starting from NULL everytime,I suppose.

I want that everytime I call the function it should get the value of updated head and start looping,but the value is not saving for head after the first call.

Comment: `Arrival* current=new Arrival(); current=head;` A memory leak right there. Please run it under `valgrind` first and fix all errors it reports. Only _then_ it will be meaningful for others to look at the code…

Comment: How to solve the memory leak,brother?

Comment: Side note: Extending a linked list [can be a one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73886789/8584929) in the vast majority of cases. Something complex with nested `if` and `while` is mostly wrong in one way or another… (Adding to a linked list should have a constant complexity, not linear etc.)

Comment: You say `Arrival * current = head;`.  Have you run this in a debugger?  The problem happens in your `else if` line where you refer to `current->next->arrAddress`.  Just because `current` has a value does not mean `current->next` has a value.

Comment: Brother,I don't know valgrind.Please help me with memory leak.

Comment: @Roman (1) Don’t throw away pointers to heap allocated memory. (2) For each `new` there must be a `delete`. (The former is more important here; the `delete` matters once you deallocate the list.)

Comment: The NEXT problem is that you are assuming that `ArrivalList::head` will be initialized to null.  For a stack object, that is not true.  It gets initialized to random stack garbage.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek,Can you show me the syntax for memory leaking preventing,please?

Comment: If managing the arrivals and departures is more important than the data structure, see `std::list`.

Comment: The solution to the leak is to not allocate an object until you need it. `Arrival* current=new Arrival();` allocates an object and points `current` at it. `current=head;`  replaces the object `current` points at with the object `head` points at. Since nothing points at what `current` pointed at any more, the object has been leaked. The solution is trivial: Remove the `=new Arrival()`.

Comment: You or someone else in your class asked [the same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77447565/private-member-value-is-changing-with-multiple-method-call).

Comment: Not only is it the same question, it's even the same buggy code!

Comment: @Roman The syntax is `delete`. (The remaining part of the recipe is to _not_ throw away pointers to allocated memory, until that memory is `delete`d.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `ArrivalList` class is not initializing its `head` member, nor is it freeing the list when finished using it, thus leaking the nodes.

And, your `addArrival()` method has several other problems as well, including:

- 1 guaranteed memory leak
- 1 potential memory leak if the new node is not added to the list.
- several more memory leaks when you accidentally wipe out your entire list if the iteration reaches the end of the list.
- dereferencing a null pointer if the iteration reaches the last node in the list.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ArrivalList
{
    private:
        struct Arrival
        {
            string arrAddress;
            double distance;
            string roadCategory;
            Arrival* next;
        };

        Arrival* head;

        ArrivalList(const ArrivalList&) {}
        ArrivalList& operator=(const ArrivalList&) { return *this; }

    public:

        ArrivalList();
        ~ArrivalList();

        bool addArrival(string oneAddress, double distance, string roadCategory);
};

ArrivalList::ArrivalList() : head(NULL) {}

ArrivalList::~ArrivalList()
{
    Arrival* current = head;
    while (current)
    {
        Arrival* temp = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = temp;
    }
}

bool ArrivalList::addArrival(string oneAddress, double distance, string roadCategory)
{
    Arrival** current = &head;

    while ((*current != NULL) && (oneAddress >= (*current)->arrAddress))
        current = &((*current)->next);

    Arrival* temp = new Arrival;
    temp->arrAddress = oneAddress;
    temp->distance = distance;
    temp->roadCategory = roadCategory;
    temp->next = *current;

    *current = temp;

    cout << head->arrAddress << endl;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    ArrivalList li;
    li.addArrival("jjjjj",0.8999,"I");
    li.addArrival("aaaaa",0.888,"k");
    li.addArrival("lllll",0.888,"k");
    li.addArrival("kkkkk",0.888,"k");
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/O2R8sx)

- On the first call, the list is empty, so `jjjjj` gets added as the new `head`.
- On the second call, `aaaaa` is "less than" `jjjjj`, so it gets added as the new `head` and `jjjjj` becomes the 2nd node in the list.
- On the third call, `lllll` is "more than" `jjjjj`, so it gets added as the last node in the list.
- On the fourth call, `kkkkk` is "more than" `jjjjj` and "less than" `lllll`, so it added between those nodes in the list.